# SQLite RawQuery Android

Tags: android, sqlite

sorry for the noob question.

But I am little stuck as to how to continue with this Method I am writing for an Android Application.

I wish to select some data from two columns in a database based on whether or not two other columns meet a certain condition. I tried creating a raw query but think that I am doing it completely wrong.

Below is the Method I wrote:

```
public String[] getDayTotals(String year, String month) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT " + sqlHelper.DAY_TOTAL + " AND " + sqlHelper.DAY + " FROM " + sqlHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + sqlHelper.YEAR + "=? AND " + sqlHelper.MONTH + "=?";
    String[] args = {year, month};

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, args);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

        int indexTotal = cursor.getColumnIndex(sqlHelper.DAY_TOTAL);
        int indexDay = cursor.getColumnIndex(sqlHelper.DAY);

        String value = cursor.getString(indexTotal);
        String day = cursor.getString(indexDay);

        sb.append(value + "," + day + "\n");

    }

    String[] temp = sb.toString().split("\n");

    return temp;
}
```

I am very new to SQL and as such am not quite sure how to continue.
I do apologize for any stupid mistakes I have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove following line from your code and try again.

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

It is moving the cursor position to first and again you are calling

```
  cursor.moveToNext()
```

and change the query as follows

```
String query = "SELECT " + sqlHelper.DAY_TOTAL + "," + sqlHelper.DAY + " FROM " + sqlHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + sqlHelper.YEAR + "=? AND " + sqlHelper.MONTH + "=?";
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked wonders, cannot believe I made such simple mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Change your query statement like the following...

```
String query = "SELECT " + sqlHelper.DAY_TOTAL + "," + sqlHelper.DAY + " FROM " + sqlHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + sqlHelper.YEAR + " = ? AND " + sqlHelper.MONTH + " = ?";
```